# EXCEL PivotTable

Tags: excel, pivot-table

DATA TAB

```
  SCHOOL    STUDENT SCORE1  SCORE2
    A   1   PASS    FAIL
    A   2   PASS    FAIL
    A   3   PASS    PASS
    A   4   FAIL    PASS
    B   5   FAIL    PASS
    B   6   PASS    PASS
    B   7   PASS    PASS
    B   8   FAIL    PASS
    B   9   FAIL    PASS
    B   10  FAIL    FAIL
```

PIVOT TAB

```
SCHOOL  SCORE1      SCORE2  
    PASS    FAIL    PASS    FAIL
A   3   1   2   2
B   2   4   5   1
```

I have a Excel with the DATA TAB and I am wondering, how do I use a pivot table to get the table show in the PIVOT TAB

I try using SCHOOL as ROW and SCORE1 and SCORE2 as COLUMN but it does not produce the outpu

Comment: Use Power Query to first unpivot the SCORE1 and SCORE2 columns, after which it will be possible to set up your desired Pivot Table.

Comment: @JosWoolley Can you show how to do this

Comment: If not knowing how to use Power Query, you could manually rearrange your data with these four columns: `School, Student, ScoreRun (1 vs 2), ScoreResult (pass vs fail)`. Your data height will double, but your pivot table will work as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Power Query` to first unpivot the *SCORE1* and *SCORE2* columns, after which it will be possible to set up your desired Pivot Table.

```
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content], 
  #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(
    Source, 
    {"SCHOOL", "STUDENT"}, 
    "Attribute", 
    "Value"
  )
in
  #"Unpivoted Other Columns"
```

Obviously you can add further steps to the above to rename columns, etc.

Comment: thanks a bunch, is this only way to do this? And where do I put the text?

Comment: You need to research Power Query in general if you're not familiar with it. I wouldn't say it's the only way to do it, though certainly the most practical, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If not sure how to use Power Query, or if you don't have access to it, then manually unpivot your data. Basically you want it took like the Reformatted data below.

[image]